# Do I need to create multiple filesystems on a virtual server to increase I/O performance?

Tags: virtualization, performance, io

I want to install Oracle on a virtual server. I don't really know the technology behind, my company just gave me a virtual server with multiple (virtual) disks.

I have the possibility to divide those disks into multiple logical volumes to partition my datafiles. But I am wondering if it is really useful, if I get better I/O performance?

If my server was not virtual and had multiple hard disks, there would be no doubt a partionning of my datafiles increase I/O performance. But what about virtual disks?

Comment: There are many rabbit holes to enter on this question.  That said, people would likely want to know things like:  Number of active paths to the pool of storage, physical configuration of the storage, max bandwidth to the storage.  What aspects of network and storage are shared vs. dedicated to your VM?  If it's all one big pool and everything is shared, then fs layout has more to do with how you organize your data and less to do with IO optimization.  If that were the case, I would just make them all PE's in LVM so you can always ask for more and add them as needed.

Comment: The problem is, I know nothing about the architecture of the hypervisor. Is it possible to find this information on my server?

Comment: You would need to ask the folks that manage the physical hardware.